# ImportError: cannot import name UDPListeners

Tags: python, python-2.7, udp, importerror, python-import

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8

from brisa.core.reactors.qtreactor import QtReactor
reactor = QtReactor()

from brisa.core.network_listeners import UDPListeners

def forward_data(data, addr=""):
    """ This is the data handler function, in this example it will simply        
        print the received data and the address from where it came
    """
    print data, "from ", addr
server = UDPListener(   "239.255.255.250",
                        port,
                        "interface",
                        data_callback = foward_data
                    )

""" Be sure to register the UDPListener’s stop function before using the

    start method, or the program doesn’t end.
"""
server.start()
reactor.add_after_stop_func(server.stop)
reactor.main()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "upnp_discovery.py", line 16, in <module>
      from brisa.core.network_listeners import UDPListeners
ImportError: cannot import name UDPListeners
```

- Before this i have installed python-brisa and QTreactor.
  http://brisa.garage.maemo.org/downloads.html
- How can i solve this import error?

Comment: in your shell try using dir(brisa.core.network_listeners) and see if there is UDPListeners in it

Comment: @FurquanKhan i tried dir(brisa.core.network_listeners) on shell and got - -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `brisa.core.network_listeners'

Comment: are you able to import the module....   say `import brisa.core.network_listeners`

Comment: @FurquanKhan yes but then i got `NameError: name 'port' is not defined`